# remove last directory in URL

Tags: javascript, regex, url, path, replace

I am trying to remove the last directory part of an URL. My URL looks like this:

`https://my_ip_address:port/site.php?path=/path/to/my/folder`.

When clicking on a button, I want to change this to

`https://my_ip_address:port/site.php?path=/path/to/my`. (Remove the last part).

I already tried `window.location.replace(/\/[A-Za-z0-9%]+$/, "")`, which results in

`https://my_ip_address:port/undefined`.

What Regex should I use to do this?

Comment: You could also just add `/../`. LOL just joking, here's the [real deal](http://regex101.com/r/nZ4jU4)

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV I am ignoring `.` in the path to avoid injection. But thanks for your link!

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV Somehow I don't get how to use `replace`: `window.location.replace(/(.*)\/.*/,"\1");` results in `https://my_ip_address:port/(.*)\/.*/`

Comment: Try something like [this](http://codepad.org/iztF30Yz) with a `$`.

Comment: do you HAVE TO use regex? There are other methods also.

Comment: @Sharky no, but what other methods would you propose? HamZaDzCyberDeV: still the same result with $1

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Explanation: Explode by "/", remove the last element with pop, join again with "/".

```
function RemoveLastDirectoryPartOf(the_url)
{
    var the_arr = the_url.split('/');
    the_arr.pop();
    return( the_arr.join('/') );
}
```

see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GWr7U/

Comment: This is unnecessarily inefficient. It will work but it will be much slower than @Thrivan Mydeen's answer.

Comment: Attention please, you will probably lose the first '/' if it exists.

Answer (score 97):

By using this code remove the last element from the Url link.

```
url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

Comment: for js: string removelastdir = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/'));

Comment: This solution is superior to the more upvoted/accepted answer. It's obvious just by looking at it, but I also created a short jsperf example to show this: https://jsperf.com/split-vs-lastindexof-2/1

Comment: Or use the window: ` window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/'))`

Comment: How would you alter this code to allow for more than one element to be removed? For example: ```https://my_ip_address:port/site.php?path=/path/to/my/folder``` down to ```https://my_ip_address:port/site.php?path=/path/to```?

Answer (score 8):

Another way to remove the end of directory path:

```
path.normalize(path.join(thePath, '..'));
```

Comment: This will not work with urls `https://` becomes `https:/`

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way I suggest to use is the mix of split, slice and join:

```
const baseUrl = 'https://my_ip_address:12345/site.php?path=/path/to/my/folder';
const newUrl = baseUrl.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/');
```

The above code has one problem - when the path ends with the slash `/` it will just remove the slash without removing the last path chunk. We can solve this by adding `.filter(Boolean)` before `.slice(0, -1)` but then if the URL has the protocol it will replace `//` with `/`.

So in more complex situations I suggest to use this safe option:

```
const baseUrl = 'https://my_ip_address:12345/site.php?path=/path/to/my/folder';

function removeLastDirectoryFromUrlSearchParam(baseUrl, paramName = 'path') {
  const url = new URL(baseUrl);
  const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
  const path = params.get(paramName);
  params.set(paramName, path.split('/').filter(Boolean).slice(0, -1).join('/'));
  url.search = params.toString();
  return url.toString();
}

const newUrl = removeLastDirectoryFromUrlSearchParam(baseUrl);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code that correctly handles `/`, "", `foo` and `/foo` (returning `/`, "", `foo`, and `/` respectively):

```js
function parentDirectory(dir: string): string {
  const lastSlash = dir.lastIndexOf('/');
  if (lastSlash === -1) {
    return dir;
  }
  if (lastSlash === 0) {
    return '/';
  }
  return dir.substring(0, lastSlash);
}
```

Just remove the `:string`s for Javascript. Maybe you want different behaviour but you should at least *consider* these edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to native libraries, `dirname` could be helpful.

---

In `node` (backend)

```
const path = require('path')
let str='https://my_ip_address:port/site.php?path=/path/to/my/folder'
console.log(path.dirname(n))
console.log(path.dirname(n)+'/')
```

The output is

```
'https://my_ip_address:port/site.php?path=/path/to/my'
'https://my_ip_address:port/site.php?path=/path/to/my'
```

---

In the Firefox browser  (see [MDN, Path Manupluation, OS.Path.dirname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/OSFile.jsm/OS.Path#OS.Path.dirname)])

```
let str='https://my_ip_address:port/site.php?path=/path/to/my/folder'
console.log(OS.path.dirname(n))
console.log(OS.path.dirname(n)+'/')
```

---

Sorry but couldn't find anything for Chromium, but maybe I just didn't look hard enough.