# Split string JavaScript in a specific way

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I want to split a string in a specific way in javascript, like if the string is C:/users/Me/AppData/elastic/elastic 1.6. I know I can split it using the split() method and use pop() and shift() to get first and last splitted string but I want to split it like, except the last string. So the answer should be like “C:/users/Me/AppData/elastic"

I did it like this,

```
str.split(str.split("/").pop()).shift()
```

I got the out put like this,

```
C:/users/Me/AppData/
```

But I want it like this,

```
C:/users/Me/AppData
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What problems are you facing?

Comment: more importantly, [what have you done so far to solve your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I want split strings in JavaScript except the last word separated by the "/".

Comment: @rayancarlon - that is a task definition... We are asking *where* you are having problems with that task...

Comment: It would be very helpful if you can show us your current attempts and any error messages that you are seeing. Showing us your code is a great way to explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove last directory in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750524/remove-last-directory-in-url)

Comment: @PhilippKief Sorry I couldn't find that, I should have searched a little more.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're saying that you want the final item in the path to be dropped. To do that, you can use `.lastIndexOf()` to get the last `/` position, and then `.slice()` up to that point if it wasn't `-1`.

```js
var str = "C:/users/Me/AppData/elastic/elastic 1.6";

var idx = str.lastIndexOf("/");
var res = str;

if (idx !== -1) {
  res = str.slice(0, idx);
}

console.log(res);
```

Or like this, which is similar to your attempt, but may be slower:

```js
var str = "C:/users/Me/AppData/elastic/elastic 1.6";

var res = str.split("/");
res.pop();
res = res.join("/");

console.log(res);
```

Your original solution does work as long as the last item doesn't appear anywhere else in the URL. Otherwise you'll get only the part before the first split item.

Answer (score 0):

If you want regex:

```
var str = "C:/users/Me/AppData/elastic/elastic 1.6"; 
str = str.replace(/\/[^\/]*$/, "");
```

The expression reads:

1. Grab everything starting from / until the end of the string.
2. There should be no / in between.
3. Replace it with nothing