# How to delete the last two characters of a number if it contains a slash (vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a little problem with my code:

```
<template slot="popover">
  <img :src="'img/articles/' + item.id + '_1.jpg'">
</template>
```

Some of my item.id numbers (Exsample: 002917/1) have a slash in them. As a result, some images are not displayed. Now I would like to delet the last two charakters when there is an slash in the number. Is there a simple solution for this?

The slash should only be deleted at this point in the code and not in another place where the item.id is used.

I am very new to vue and javascript so please have mercy.

I am using the vue version 16.13.1

Comment: To clarify, you want to delete the `/` and also the `1`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34035933

Comment: Yes exactly! Can you show me how i can use it on my code? I am sorry for the trouble...

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `split`. This will always give the correct result, even if there is no slash contained in the id.

```vue
<template slot="popover">
  <img :src="'img/articles/' + item.id.split('/')[0] + '_1.jpg'">
</template>
```

Comment: It Works! Thanks! Can you explain how it works?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) here as:

```js
const num = "002917/1";
const result = num.includes("/") 
                ? num.slice(0, -2) 
                : num;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: handleSlashes() {  
const num = item.id;  
const result = num.includes("/")   
                ? num.slice(0, -2)   
                : num;  
    },

Comment: Can I use it like this?

Comment: And in at this poit in the code do I use this? <img :src="'img/articles/' + result + '_1.jpg'">

Comment: I very new to js I am sorry.

Comment: @Crysanthes Yes, you cna use it